# Moving CodeIgniter project to live server

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

i have read around about changing config.php and database.php, but nothing works.
i have removed index.php using rewrite so both my localhost and server return 404 error (expected).

i can open other page by typing directly from URL=http://localhost/auth/login

but i get error 'no input file specified' on live server with URL=http://nataliakiantoro.esy.es/auth/login

my folder path in localhost, i use wamp

www

-nk

--.htaccess

--application,system,dll

folder path in real server

-public_html(the most outer i can get, i think this is the root)

-.htaccess

-application,system,dll

```
'hostname' => 'mysql.idhostinger.com',
'username' => 'xxxxxx_admin',
'password' => 'xxxxxxx',
'database' => 'xxxxxxx_nk',

$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.nataliakiantoro.esy.es/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

i believe thats all relevant part that i tweak and read around
i even create an index.html and change the config accordingly but its still not working

my local php is 5.5.12
live server php is 5.6.21

so anything else i haven't done yet?

thanks in advance

Comment: are you working on local server then 'hostname' => 'mysql.idhostinger.com',   hostname is right ?

Comment: if you want URL=http://localhost/auth/login  then your base url value is wrong $config['base_url'] = 'http://nataliakiantoro.esy.es/';

Comment: try typing the full url for your site including the controller name

Comment: @ReenaMori i believe my hostname is correct, it was written in the cpanel under MySql Host. I have tried the URL u suggested, not working

Comment: ok then problem occurred when you set htaccess for removing index.php form url i am right?

Comment: i dont know, i did all that in localhost, then after i manage to get login done i want to test it in server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
database.php
'hostname' => 'hostname',
'username' => 'xxxxxx_admin',
'password' => 'xxxxxxx',
'database' => 'xxxxxxx_nk',

config.php
$config['base_url'] = 'host_directory_path/project_folder_name';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';

.htaccess file put on root_directory 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project_Folder_name
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: uh, that QSA thing is the cause. Thanks for your help